# Recovering CW complex from a quotient

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Let $X,Y,A,B$ be CW-complexes such that $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$ are subcomplexes. Assume that $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$ are good pairs if necessary. Suppose there is a relative homeomorphism $f:(X,A)\to (Y,B)$, meaning that $f$ is a map of pairs such that the induced map $X/A\to Y/B$ is a homeomorphism.

> If we don't know $Y$, but we know $X,A,B$ and how $f$ is defined on $A$, can
> we recover $Y$ (at least up to homotopy) from the fact that $f$ is a relative homeomorphism?

Maybe a more precise way to state the question is: if we have the complexes $X,A,B$ with $A\subseteq X$ a subcomplex and a map $f|_A:A\to B$, can we find a complex $Y$ containing $B$ as a subcomplx such that there is a relative homeomorphism $f:(X,A)\to (Y,B)$ extending $f|_A$?

Since we know that $Y/B \cong X/A$, my guess is that we can take $X/A$, and in the 0-cell corresponding to the class $[A]$ we would attach $B$ in a way that is consistent with $f|_A$, so that $f$ outside $A$ is just the identity.

I'm not sure if this works or if we need further assumptions on $f|_A$. The source of this problem is a construction made by Stasheff in [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1963-108-02/S0002-9947-1963-99936-3/S0002-9947-1963-99936-3.pdf) (Construction 8, page 279-280), where he builds spaces in an inductive way via relative homeomorphisms of the form

$$(X_i,A_i)\xrightarrow{\alpha_i}(E_i,E_{i-1})$$

that are defined only on $A_i$. He later state who $E_1$ is and describes from this how $\alpha_2$ identifies $A_2$ with $E_{1}$, but never really describes $E_2$. There are some theorems specifying the homotopy type of these spaces, but the proof seem very implicit to me and I can't really understand what is going on.

Comment: Note that the standard definition of 'relative homeomorphism' is a map of pairs $f:(X,A)\rightarrow (Y,B)$ such thathe induced map$X-A\rightarrow Y-B$ is a homeomorphism (and not between the quotient spaces). I don't think there is any difference if both pairs are good. Probably ask Paul Frost.

Comment: I read [here](http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~tvogel/Vorlesungen/AlgTop/skript-top1.pdf) that it was between the quotients, but thanks for the clarification. In that case I still believe my idea makes sense, even though I'm not sure about the details.

Comment: I checked the definition I gave in Spanier's and Bredon's books. I think in your case where everything is CW that $Y$ is just the adjunction space $B\cup_fX$. Certainly $(X,A)\rightarrow(B,B\cup_fX)$ is a relative homeomorphism (in either sense), and there is another $(B,B\cup_fX)\rightarrow (B,Y)$ induced by $f$. At least maybe you can reduce the problem to considering the pair $(B,B\cup_fX)$

Comment: Thank you, I think the pair should be in reverse order, $(B\cup_f X, B)$ right?

Comment: Yes! That is what I should have written.